# Commerce Kickstart: How To Add Sort Fields To Search API?

Tags: search, commerce

I've been playing with the Search API and I can add new Facet Displays and filters, but no matter what I try I can't get any fields other than Price, Latest and Title to appear as Sort options. What's the 'trick'?

Answer (score 1):

For other travelers, the answer is that it's a bug with a patch that has not been made part of the official distribution as of 26 Sep 2014. See #6 for the patch.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2202093